# Power Screen ON and OFF android device programatically

Tags: android, screen, device

I need on my Android App to switch the screen off (like when user presses power button) and after some time (for example 5 minutes) switch back on (like when user presses power button).

I do not have my device rooted, so "goToSleep" and so should not work...

What alternatives do I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quickboot or Fast Reboot for your need. Please check the below android market for further details.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot&hl=en

Comment: Hello, as I refer I do not want to root my device, and I need it on my app code. Thanks.